# how to send an unauthorized response for annotation @CurrentUser

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

how to send an unauthorized response for annotation @CurrentUser
i have annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CurrentUser {
    boolean required() default true;
}
```

have argument resolver

```
public class CurrentUserIdMethodArgumentResolver extends AbstractCurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver<CurrentUserId> {
    public CurrentUserIdMethodArgumentResolver() {
        super(CurrentUserId.class, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRequired(CurrentUserId annotation) {
        return annotation.required();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object resolveName(String name, MethodParameter parameter, NativeWebRequest request) throws Exception {
        return (getCurrentUser() != null)? getCurrentUser().getId() : null;
    }
}
```

configure spring security

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                            .antMatchers(REACT_API_PERMITTED_URL, PERMITTED_SOCKET_PUBLIC_TOPIC, PERMITTED_SOCKET_ENDPOINT1, PERMITTED_SOCKET_ENDPOINT2).permitAll()
                            .antMatchers(SOCKET_PRIVATE_ENDPOINT, NOT_PERMITTED_SOCKET_ENDPOINT1, NOT_PERMITTED_SOCKET_ENDPOINT2).authenticated()
                            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                            .antMatchers("/moderator/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().headers()
                        .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and().formLogin()
                        .loginPage(REACT_API_USER_LOGIN)
                        .permitAll()
                             .successHandler(successHandler)
                             .failureHandler(failureHandler)

                        .and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilterAfter(userFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(adminConfirmFilter, SwitchUserFilter.class)

                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl(REACT_API_USER_LOGOUT)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(REACT_API)
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(defaultLogoutHandler)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll();
    }
```

I want in my controller return to HTTP.STATUS.unauthorized  calling it, if the user is not authorized

```
 @GetMapping("/test")
 public User test(@CurrentUser User current) {
return current
}
```

Now I have status 400, BAD REQUEST, but want configure this status

Comment: You could use Spring Security's annotation `Secured` or `Preauthorize` to make sure, that only authenticated users are allowed.

Comment: maybe there is another way to handle this annotation @CurrentUser ?

Comment: Obtaining the user and doing an authorization check are different things. Also why create your own, you are already using Spring Security which has an annotation to inject the current user already. Checking authorization should be done either through the URLs or `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to its question so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver userMethodArgumentResolver() {
        return new CurrentUserMethodArgumentResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Object resolveName(String name, MethodParameter parameter, NativeWebRequest request) throws Exception {
                SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
                CurrentUser annotation = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(CurrentUser.class);
                boolean anonymousUser = securityContext.getAuthentication() instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
                if (annotation.required() && anonymousUser) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("access is denied");
                }
                return super.resolveName(name, parameter, request);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> list) {
        list.add(userMethodArgumentResolver());
        super.addArgumentResolvers(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring already have this, just add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to your configuration and annotate your secured method with special annotation `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` or `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN)")` etc:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConf43547 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ....
    }
}
```

and in your controller

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") //this annotation better add to service method @Service
public String test() {
    return "abc"
}
```

or 
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getOk(Authentication authentication) {
   return authentication.getName();
}
```